# Automated query on Data-Explorer make Everything useless

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

Since jan 16 at 14:59 (currently page 524 of Everything) there has been a regular set of queries from a non-logged in user. Can we have an "Almost Everything" that skips either these automated queries if they've been done in some organised way, or non-logged-in users?

Comment: Can somebody review my banning code :)

Comment: If you can provide a link to a query that was run during that time that causes you grief, I'm sure they would be happy to look into it and exclude it ;)

Comment: @drachenstern I don't know how much of your comment was covered by the smilie, but it is a new query each time, and there's 2-4 a minute.

Comment: My smily was for the diamond mods. My question to you is do you know the name of any of the queries that are running 2-4 a minute at a time?

Comment: @drachenstern Sam has fixed the problem, but you could see the problem easily looking at the Everything tab. And, no, every query was a new unnamed one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fine then, spoil all the fun for anonymous, see if I care.

20,000 queries deleted, another ip is in the blacklist. **ALL** anonymous users must solve a Captcha before running any queries.

[image: Thank you, sir]

Comment: Very nice! Well done.